# How to use FFmpeg blend/difference filter mode to identify frame differences between two videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm trying to verify if a video compressed with a lossless codec is mathematically identical to the raw video. In [How to compare/show the difference between 2 videos in ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774996/how-to-compare-show-the-difference-between-2-videos-in-ffmpeg), an answer described using the [FFmpeg blend filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend-1) to create an output video that allows you to visualize the differences between two input videos. I'd like to know if there's a way to have FFmpeg output some text-based output when it locates frames in the two videos that are not identical. Doing this would be quicker than opening the resulting blended video and looking for any difference across the entire video.

I did attempt to use the the MD5 hash method that was also described in that answer, however, for videos that differ in pixel formats (for example), the MD5 hash does not match (as the poster mentioned they might not) while the blended video indicates they are the same.

Comment: Use blackframe after blend. See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/19869/ for a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1615310/how-to-use-ffmpeg-blend-difference-filter-mode-to-identify-frame-differences-bet?noredirect=1#comment2463520_1615310) from [Gyan](https://superuser.com/users/114058/gyan), I was able to get most of what I was after:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i video1.avi -i video2.avi -filter_complex "blend=all_mode=difference,blackframe=amount=0:threshold=1,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=99.9999:function=less,metadata=print:file=-" -an -v 0 -f null -
```

**blackframe**

- *amount=0* - Detect all frames - even those that have no black pixels.
- *threshold=1* - Define black pixels as having luminance below 1 (i.e. 0).

When the videos match exactly, there is no output. When there is some difference, the output looks like this:

```
frame:0    pts:66667   pts_time:0.066667
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=26
frame:1    pts:166667  pts_time:0.166667
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=94
...
```

I initially tried `...lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=100:function=less...` but I was seeing frames with *pblack* values of 100. Not sure if this is due to a rounding error somewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to print the actual frame number from the input videos? For example, if a 10 frame video doesn't match on frame 3 and frame 7, I'd like it to print "frame:3...frame:7" instead of "frame:0...frame:1".